# Problem 5.21 in Boyd's Convex Optimization about strong duality failing

Tags: calculus, convex-optimization

Exercise 5.21 in [Boyd & Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/) asks us to study the problem of minimizing $e^{-x}$ subject to $x^2/y \leq 0$ with domain $\mathcal{D} = \{(x,y)\ |\ y > 0\}$. Now, $x^2/y \leq 0$ with $y > 0$ clearly forces $x = 0$, so the optimal value is $e^{-0} = 1$. The Lagrangian for this problem is

$$L(x, \lambda) = e^{-x} + \lambda \frac{x^2}{y}$$

and so we have the dual function

$$g(\lambda) = \inf_{x} \left( e^{-x} + \lambda \frac{x^2}{y} \right) $$

We have $g(0) = 0$, and for $\lambda > 0$ since the Lagrangian is convex in $x$ we can obtain the minimum by differentiation. I get the result

$$g(\lambda) = \frac{\lambda W\left( \frac{y}{2\lambda} \right) \left( W\left( \frac{y}{2\lambda} \right) + 2 \right)}{y}$$

which I have checked with Wolfram so I believe it's correct. Miraculously, Wolfram can compute this derivative and tells me

$$g'(\lambda) = \frac{W\left( \frac{y}{2\lambda} \right)^2}{y}$$

This is strictly positive for $\lambda > 0$, and $g(0) = 0$ is also clearly not the maximum, so (since theory tells us $g$ is concave) I expect to find the maximum as $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} g(\lambda)$.

To compute that, I noted (by setting $u = y/(2\lambda)$ in what follows) that

$$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \lambda W\left( \frac{y}{2\lambda} \right) = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{y}{2u} W(u) = \frac{y}{2}$$

since Wolfram tells me $\lim_{x \to 0} W(x)/x = 1$. Now since $ W \left( \frac{y}{2\lambda} \right) + 2$ goes to $2$ as $\lambda \to \infty$, it seems I get $$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} g(\lambda) = 1!$$

This would vindicate strong duality, which wasn't supposed to hold. Furthermore Boyd asks me to compute the optimal solution to the dual problem, which doesn't seem to be attained for any finite value. Am I missing something here?

Note: There is a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268139/problem-calculating-the-dual-of-a-convex-problem) about this exercise but it does not answer my question.

Comment: Having the limit of $g(\lambda)=1$ but no specific  value of $\lambda$ with $g(\lambda)=1$  is an example  of strong duality not holding.   This is referred to as non-attainment.

Comment: I suspected so, but that is specifically not how Boyd defines strong duality so it's a little frustrating.

Comment: Looking back at this exercise, I see that $d^{*}=0$.  If $\lambda<0$, then the inf is $-\infty$ (just take $x \rightarrow \infty$ .)  If $\lambda \geq 0$, then the inf is $0$.  I can't find the error in your calculation, but be assured that it's there.

Comment: But Wolfram seems to agree, see e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+e%5E%28-x%29+%2B+%283%2F5%29+x%5E2

Comment: Do you agree that the inf is 0 if $\lambda \geq 0$?  If $\lambda<0$, then we can take the limit as $x \rightarrow +\infty$ and $y=1$, and the Lagrangian goes to $-\infty$.   Because this is unbounded, the inf can't be found just by setting the derivative equal to 0.

Comment: Note that $g(\lambda)$ is defined as the inf with respect to $x$ and $y$ of the Lagrangian.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right, that was silly of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lagrangian is
$$L(x, y, \lambda) = \mathrm{e}^{- x} + \lambda \frac{x^2}{y}.$$

The dual function is
$$g(\lambda) = \inf_{\mathcal{D}} \left(\mathrm{e}^{- x} + \lambda \frac{x^2}{y}\right)
 = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
  0 & \lambda \ge 0\\
  -\infty & \lambda < 0.
 \end{array}\right.$$
where $\mathcal{D} = \{(x,y) : ~ y > 0\}$ is the domain.

---

*Remarks*: We may deal with $\inf_{\mathcal{D}} \left(\mathrm{e}^{- x} + \lambda \frac{x^2}{y}\right)$ in another way.

For $\lambda > 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \inf_{\mathcal{D}} \left(\mathrm{e}^{- x} + \lambda \frac{x^2}{y}\right)
 &= \inf_{y > 0} 
 \inf_{x} \left(\mathrm{e}^{- x} + \lambda \frac{x^2}{y}\right)\\
 &= \inf_{y > 0}  \frac{\lambda W\left( \frac{y}{2\lambda} \right) \left( W\left( \frac{y}{2\lambda} \right) + 2 \right)}{y}\\
 &= \lim_{y\to \infty}  \frac{\lambda W\left( \frac{y}{2\lambda} \right) \left( W\left( \frac{y}{2\lambda} \right) + 2 \right)}{y} \tag{1}\\
 &= \lim_{u\to \infty} \left[\frac{W(u)^2}{2u} + \frac{W(u)}{u}\right]\\
 &= 0 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
where we obtain (1) by using
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\frac{\lambda W\left( \frac{y}{2\lambda} \right) \left( W\left( \frac{y}{2\lambda} \right) + 2 \right)}{y}
= - \frac{\lambda [W\left(\frac{y}{2\lambda}\right)]^2}{y^2} < 0,$$
and we obtain (2) by using
$\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{W(u)}{u} = 0$
and $\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{W(u)}{\sqrt{u}} = 0$
(using L'Hopital's rule and $W'(u) = \frac{1}{u}\, \frac{W(u)}{1 + W(u)}$).

Comment: I can see the inf is zero, but I'm not sure I follow your second argument. Why is that limit zero due to the derivative being negative?

Comment: @Pedro I edited it to make it clear.

Comment: Alright, thanks (I'll award the bounty when it becomes available in 11 hours).